# Displaying WooCommerce product images in DK PDF Template

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce

I am trying to adapt this code to echoing out a fore each for the image gallary of the products on woocommerce into a pdf. If you could point me into the correct direction that would be great

```
<?php
/**
* dkpdf-index.php
* This template is used to display the content in the PDF
*
* Do not edit this template directly,
* copy this template and paste in your theme inside a directory named dkpdf
*/
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="all" />
        <?php
            $wp_head = get_option( 'dkpdf_print_wp_head', '' );
            if( $wp_head == 'on' ) {
                wp_head();
            }
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background:#fff;
                font-size: 6pt;
            }
          /* fontawesome compatibility */
          .fa {
              font-family: fontawesome;
              display: inline-block;
              font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
              font-size: inherit;
              text-rendering: auto;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
              -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
              transform: translate(0, 0);
          }

                <?php
            // get pdf custom css option
            $css = get_option( 'dkpdf_pdf_custom_css', '' );
            echo $css;
        ?>
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
            global $post;
            $pdf = get_query_var( 'pdf' );
            $post_type = get_post_type( $pdf );
            if( $pdf && $post_type == 'product'  ) {
                $title = get_the_title();
                if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
                    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'FULL' );
                }


                $description = get_the_excerpt();
          $description2 = get_post($item['product_id'])->post_content;
                $product = new WC_Product( $post->ID );
                $link = get_the_permalink();

          ?>


          <?php function yikes_custom_product_tabs_shortcode( $args ) {
            global $post;

            // Define our default values
            $defaults = array(
                'product_id' => $post->ID,
                'tab_number' => 'all',
            );

            // Let the user-defined values override our defaults
            $values = is_array( $args ) ? array_merge( $defaults, $args ) : $defaults;

            // Make sure we have a product ID and that the product ID is for a product
            if ( empty( $values['product_id'] ) || ! empty( $values['product_id'] ) && get_post_type( $values['product_id'] ) !== 'product' ) {
                return;
            }

            // Fetch our tabs
            $tabs = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], 'yikes_woo_products_tabs', true );

            // Get just the specified tab. (minus tab number by one so it starts at 0)
            $tabs = absint( $values['tab_number'] ) < 1 ? $tabs : ( isset( $tabs[ absint( $values['tab_number'] ) - 1 ] ) ? array( $tabs[ absint( $values['tab_number'] ) - 1 ] ) : array() );

            if ( empty( $tabs ) ) {
                return;
            }

            // Debug statement to show all tab data. Feel free to remove.
            // echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $tabs ); echo '</pre>';

            $html = '';

            // Loop through the tabs and display each one
            foreach( $tabs as $tab ) {
              $html .= '<tr>
                <td  style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; text-align:center; line-height:2em; background:#f8f8f8;">';
                $html .= '<h5>' . $tab['title'] . '</h5>';
              $html .= '</td></tr>';
              $html .= '<tr>
                <td  style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center; line-height:2em;">';
                $html .= '<p style="font-size:10px;">' . $tab['content'] . '</p>';
              $html .= '</td></tr>';
            }

            // Make sure to return your content, do not echo it.
            return $html;
          }

          add_shortcode( 'custom_product_tabs', 'yikes_custom_product_tabs_shortcode' ); ?>

          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;text-align:center; color:#fff;"  class="bg-dark">
                <h3 style="color:#fff;"><?php echo esc_attr( $title );?></h3>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td  style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center; line-height:2em;">
                <p style="font-size:10px;"><?php echo $description;?></p>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom:15px; text-align:center; line-height:2em; ">
                <?php  if( $thumbnail ) { echo $thumbnail; } ?>


              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; text-align:center; line-height:2em; background:#f8f8f8;">
                <h5>DESCRIPTION</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center; line-height:2em;">
                <p style="font-size:10px;"><?php echo $description2;?> <?php echo wpautop( $post->post_content ); ?></p>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php echo yikes_custom_product_tabs_shortcode('custom_product_tabs'); ?>

          </table>


            <?php }
        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```